# Table record update stopped by Foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, derby

I have a problem in updating records to a **derby db** table with foreign key. Consider the two tables *QUESTIONCHOICE* and *QUESTIONANSWER* below. The records in table *QUESTIONANSWER* is a subset of *QUESTIONCHOICE* and has a foreign key constraint to make sure *QUESTIONANSWER* table is always subset of *QUESTIONCHOICE* table.

Now i am trying to update a record in *QUESTIONCHOICE* table using the query below and the update is stopped by foreign key constraint.

**update "USER"."QUESTIONCHOICE" set "CHOICE"='GET1' where "QID"=10001 and "CHOICE"='GET';**

**UPDATE on table 'QUESTIONCHOICE' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'QUESTIONANSWER_FK' for key (10001,GET).  The statement has been rolled back.**

How am i supposed to update the records in the table QUESTIONCHOICE?
i can delete the record in QUESTIONANSWER table update my record in QUESTIONCHOICE table and then insert the record in QUESTIONANSWER. but it doesnt sounds good to me.

Also can i create QUESTIONANSWER as a VIEW instead a TABLE, If so how will i make a subset of QUESTIONCHOICE table?

please suggest.

Thanks,

-Vijay Selvaraj

```
----------
CREATE TABLE USER.QUESTIONCHOICE(
QID INT NOT NULL,
Choice VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT QUESTIONCHOICE_PK PRIMARY KEY (QID, Choice),
CONSTRAINT QUESTIONCHOICE_FK FOREIGN KEY (QID)
    REFERENCES user.questionbank (QuestionID)
);

----------
create table USER.QUESTIONANSWER(
QID INT NOT NULL,
Answer VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT QUESTIONANSWER_PK PRIMARY KEY (QID, Answer),
CONSTRAINT QUESTIONANSWER_FK FOREIGN KEY (QID, Answer)
    REFERENCES USER.QUESTIONCHOICE (QID, Choice)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you add a additional column to the QUESTIONCHOICE table to mark a row as the answer row, this way, the view also can be created by applying a constraint on the answer column.

Comment: Yes even i got the idea in mind. Let me introduce a column and make the table design simple. Thanks.